# Is it possible to import an excel file to smartsheet API?

Tags: java, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

Are there any functions or methods in smartsheet API 1.1 that allow you to create a new sheet or update an existing sheet based on an csv or xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the Smartsheet API does not have a method to import a CSV or XML File.

However, you can import the CSV in the Smartsheet application. More info [here](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/504553-importing-files-to-create-new-sheets)

Also, you can use a Java library to read the CSV or XML file and then issue the appropriate API calls to create a new sheet and insert the rows. This can be done more efficiently using the 2.0 version of the [Smartsheet API](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/).

Comment: I could only find the SDK's for the API 1.1 as they have not been changed to handle the 2.0 yet according to github.

Comment: You are in luck, Smartsheet just released a new version of the SDK that uses API 2.0. You can download the Java SDK by updating your Maven pom to point to version 2.0.0. https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk

Answer (score 1):

There is way to do this now in version 2.2.0. Only XLSX file is supported.

```
Sheet sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.ImportXlsSheet("SampleSheet.xlsx", null, 0, null);
sheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheet.Id.Value, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```